# How to use \textchi in math mode

Tags: macros

I write Greek letter Chi using `\textchi` from `\usepackage{tipa}`, but it is only for textmode.
I would like to use it also in math mode, like in that situation, when defining Dirichlet's L-function:

```
$L(\textchi,s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \textchi(n)/n^{s}$
```

equation is math mode and it looks good but then I can't use `\textchi` within it.

Comment: Welcome! Said in other words, you want an upright chi, as opposed to the italic symbol provided by `\chi`?

Comment: @egreg I will try \chi. I don't know many commands, Detexify app proposed me only \textchi when I wrote shape there. I don't care how that letter will look like as long as it is obvious it is chi.

Comment: If you want an upright  χ  you may use the `\upchi` command from package `upgreek`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the standard `\chi` command.

If you're adamant about an upright letter, you could use `upgreek` (but I don't recommend it, because the letter shapes are quite peculiar) or define your own symbol. However, if you change the default font for the document, the definition would need to be updated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{upgreek}

% for the third solution
\DeclareFontEncoding{LGR}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LGR}{cmr}{m}{n}

\DeclareSymbolFont{upgreek}{LGR}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varchi}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`q}
%%%

\begin{document}

Standard \verb|\chi| command
\[
L(\chi,s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\chi(n)}{n^{s}}
\]

With \verb|\upchi| from \texttt{upgreek}
\[
L(\upchi,s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\upchi(n)}{n^{s}}
\]

With \verb|\varchi| defined above
\[
L(\varchi,s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\varchi(n)}{n^{s}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `\upchi` command in math mode with numerous packages, including `unicode-math` and `upgreek`.  A few support a slightly-different command, such as `\chiup` or `\otherchi`.  The `eulervm` package makes `\chi` upright.

You can use `\mathrm{\chi}` with `stix`, `stix2`, or `isomath` with the `OMLmathrm` option and one of the upright fonts from `mathdesign` loaded.

The `unicode-math` package also lets you use `\symup{chi}` or `\mupchi`, and it will make `\mathrm{chi}` a synonym for `\symup{chi}` if you load the package with the `mathrm=sym` option.

Finally, you can use `\textnormal{\textchi}` in either text or math mode.  However, you probably do not want to use a `tipa` glyph as a math symbol.  You might load a Greek font and then enable `\textalpha`, etc., with `\usepackage{textalpha}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this,`\text{χ}`.

Comment: Note that since `\text` follows the text out side of math, this might not be a good idea (one can for example end up getting an italic χ if the text context is italic.